# None value on "How to think like a computer scientist 3" exercise

Tags: python, nonetype, pyscripter

I'm learning python 3.4 programming with the great book "How to Think Like a Computer Scientist 3". I have some doubts about my response to exercise 5.14.2, which reads:

> You go on a wonderful holiday (perhaps to jail, if you don’t like happy exercises) leaving on day number 3 (a Wednesday). You return home after 137 sleeps. Write a general version of the program which asks for the starting day number, and the length of your stay, and it will tell you the name of day of the week you will return on.

I'm trying to not use any coding techniques involving concepts in the next pages of the week, and my response is:

```
def dias_semana(x):
    if x == 1:
        print("lunes")
    elif x == 2:
        print("martes")
    elif x == 3:
        print("miercoles")
    elif x == 4:
        print("jueves")
    elif x == 5:
        print("viernes")
    elif x == 6:
        print("sábado")
    elif x == 7:
        print("domingo")
    else:
        print("déjate de wear culiao")

def vacaciones():
    diaempiezo = int(input("Día que empiezo"))
    cuantosdias = int(input("días de vacaciones"))
    díavuelta = (diaempiezo + cuantosdias) % 7
    print(dias_semana(díavuelta))

vacaciones()
```

The program works, and prints the correct value. However, it also prints a "None" value after the day of return.

Why this is happening? I don't understand why it prints the "None".

Answer (score 4):

You're printing within `dias_semana`, and then printing what it returns-- but you never return anything. The default return value for a function which doesn't return anything explicitly, is `None`.

Either just call `dias_semana` in the `vacaciones` function without printing it, or else change the `print` statements inside of  `dias_semana` to `return` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `dias_semana` doesn't return anything and in that case a function implicitly returns `None`. And by doing `print(dias_semana(díavuelta))` you actually do the following:

```
return_value = dias_semana(díavuelta)
print(return_value)
```

And `return_value` is `None`. One way to fix is to return the value in `dias_semana` and not directly print anything. Or to not use the `print` function in the `vacaciones` function.